fallocate not defined in QEMU 7.2.14 trying to compile on windows using mingw
Trying to compile QEMU 7.2.14 so I can use HAXM virtualizer to accelerate it (not using hyperv) and I'm getting an error saying that the fallocate function is not found in file qemu/softmmu/physmem.c line 3600, I have already tried looking for a fix but I can't find one & this function seems to be linux specific so I have no idea why it's used even though qemu is specified to be windows buildable
Using mingw64 (latest version) with
./configure --enable-gtk --enable-sdl --target-list=x86_64-softmmu --disable-werror --disable-stack-protector
make -j

Error info
[1038/1346] Compiling C object libqemu-x86_64-softmmu.fa.p/softmmu_physmem.c.obj
FAILED: libqemu-x86_64-softmmu.fa.p/softmmu_physmem.c.obj
"cc" "-m64" "-mcx16" "-Ilibqemu-x86_64-softmmu.fa.p" "-I." "-I.." "-Itarget/i386" "-I../target/i386" "-Iqapi" "-Itrace" "-Iui" "-Iui/shader" "-IE:/msys64/mingw64/include/pixman-1" "-IE:/msys64/mingw64/include/capstone" "-IE:/msys64/mingw64/include/glib-2.0" "-IE:/msys64/mingw64/lib/glib-2.0/include" "-fdiagnostics-color=auto" "-Wall" "-Winvalid-pch" "-std=gnu11" "-O2" "-g" "-iquote" "." "-iquote" "E:/source/repos/qemu" "-iquote" "E:/source/repos/qemu/include" "-iquote" "E:/source/repos/qemu/tcg/i386" "-U_FORTIFY_SOURCE" "-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2" "-fno-pie" "-no-pie" "-D_GNU_SOURCE" "-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64" "-D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE" "-Wstrict-prototypes" "-Wredundant-decls" "-Wundef" "-Wwrite-strings" "-Wmissing-prototypes" "-fno-strict-aliasing" "-fno-common" "-fwrapv" "-Wold-style-declaration" "-Wold-style-definition" "-Wtype-limits" "-Wformat-security" "-Wformat-y2k" "-Winit-self" "-Wignored-qualifiers" "-Wempty-body" "-Wnested-externs" "-Wendif-labels" "-Wexpansion-to-defined" "-Wimplicit-fallthrough=2" "-Wno-missing-include-dirs" "-Wno-shift-negative-value" "-Wno-psabi" "-DNEED_CPU_H" "-DCONFIG_TARGET=\"x86_64-softmmu-config-target.h\"" "-DCONFIG_DEVICES=\"x86_64-softmmu-config-devices.h\"" -MD -MQ libqemu-x86_64-softmmu.fa.p/softmmu_physmem.c.obj -MF "libqemu-x86_64-softmmu.fa.p/softmmu_physmem.c.obj.d" -o libqemu-x86_64-softmmu.fa.p/softmmu_physmem.c.obj "-c" ../softmmu/physmem.c
../softmmu/physmem.c: In function 'ram_block_discard_range':
../softmmu/physmem.c:3600:19: error: implicit declaration of function 'fallocate'; did you mean '_alloca'? [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
 3600 |             ret = fallocate(rb->fd, FALLOC_FL_PUNCH_HOLE | FALLOC_FL_KEEP_SIZE, start, length);
      |                   ^~~~~~~~~
      |                   _alloca
../softmmu/physmem.c:3600:19: warning: nested extern declaration of 'fallocate' [-Wnested-externs]
[1039/1346] Compiling C object libqemu-x86_64-softmmu.fa.p/softmmu_icount.c.obj
[1040/1346] Compiling C object libqemu-x86_64-softmmu.fa.p/page-vary.c.obj
[1041/1346] Compiling C object libqemu-x86_64-softmmu.fa.p/softmmu_dirtylimit.c.obj
[1042/1346] Compiling C object libqemu-x86_64-softmmu.fa.p/softmmu_qtest.c.obj
[1043/1346] Compiling C object libqemu-x86_64-softmmu.fa.p/dump_dump.c.obj
[1044/1346] Compiling C object libqemu-x86_64-softmmu.fa.p/cpu.c.obj
[1045/1346] Compiling C object libqemu-x86_64-softmmu.fa.p/disas.c.obj
[1046/1346] Compiling C object libqemu-x86_64-softmmu.fa.p/gdbstub_gdbstub.c.obj
[1047/1346] Compiling C object libqemu-x86_64-softmmu.fa.p/migration_target.c.obj
[1048/1346] Compiling C object libqemu-x86_64-softmmu.fa.p/migration_dirtyrate.c.obj
[1049/1346] Compiling C object libqemu-x86_64-softmmu.fa.p/tcg_region.c.obj
[1050/1346] Compiling C object libqemu-x86_64-softmmu.fa.p/softmmu_memory.c.obj
[1051/1346] Compiling C object libqemu-x86_64-softmmu.fa.p/monitor_misc.c.obj
[1052/1346] Compiling C object libqemu-x86_64-softmmu.fa.p/tcg_optimize.c.obj
[1053/1346] Compiling C object libqemu-x86_64-softmmu.fa.p/migration_ram.c.obj
[1054/1346] Compiling C object libqemu-x86_64-softmmu.fa.p/tcg_tcg.c.obj
[1055/1346] Compiling C object libqemu-x86_64-softmmu.fa.p/target_i386_tcg_translate.c.obj
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
make[1]: *** [Makefile:165: run-ninja] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/e/source/repos/qemu/build'
make: *** [GNUmakefile:11: all] Error 2

I tried to find alternative functions to fallocate and it seem like this function is for file creation but there is no libs/alternative's that would not require manual implementation on windows using ntos as far as I could find, I was expecting qemu to compile without any errors

Are you using MSYS? Have you followed all the steps documented here https://wiki.qemu.org/Hosts/W32 in the section "Native builds with MSYS2"?

Everything in those instructions I've done correctly but qemu did not account for soft-mmu compiling on windows properly since they are using linux specific functions for file allocation

Seems like you are right then, in such case I would consider it a bug, you may want to report it to QEMU devs.

On second thought, if you want to report it, maybe try building the latest release first just to be sure.

On the latest version it does work but they don't support the HAXM accelerator on newer versions past 7.2 which is what I need

The fix for this is just to disable the section that uses the function using the macro and since its not mandatory to wipe pages it doesn't cause no issues, however using qemu with haxm doesn't even work anymore with qemu so if you came here trying to fix this I would just recommend using linux for qemu cause KVM is faster either way
